# Insert new line to bash prompts

Tags: linux, bash, newline

This seems like a common question, but I can't find this anywhere on Google nor SO.  Please point me to the article if you find one.

How do I insert a new line in bash prompts (when you just press ENTER), similar to that in Windows prompt?

Linux:

```
$
$
$
```

Windows:

```
C:\>

C:\>

C:\>
```

I need that extra space in between.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the PS1 Bash prompt variable:

```
PS1="\n$PS1"
```