# Print a blank line in bash only after output

Tags: bash

#### Question:

I would like bash to print a blank line before the next prompt, but only if there has been output to the terminal.

#### Partial solution:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198392/3385432) proposes
  changing the bash custom prompt to `PS1="\n$PS1"`. This results in bash producing a blank line before every terminal prompt.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859615/3385432) improves upon this slightly by preventing a newline before the first prompt. This is accomplished via the `PROMPT_COMMAND` bash variable and a function that sets a variable the first time it is called.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467631/how-to-add-new-line-after-bash-command-before-output) tries to accomplish something similar (a new line before output instead of after output), but the answers provided only produce newlines for every prompt.

#### Current behavior:

```
[user@host ~]$ ls
Desktop  Downloads  Dropbox  Music 

[user@host ~]$ vim 

[user@host ~]$ ssh login

[user@login ~]$ uptime
 08:01:11 up 50 days, 15:15, 15 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.03

[user@login ~]$ vim file

[user@login ~]$ cd dir/foo

[user@login foo]$ mkdir bar

[user@login bar]$ cd bar

[user@login bar]$ vim file2

[user@login bar]$ ls
file2

[user@login bar]$
```

#### Desired behavior:

```
[user@host ~]$ ls
Desktop  Downloads  Dropbox  Music 

[user@host ~]$ vim 
[user@host ~]$ ssh login
[user@login ~]$ uptime
 08:01:11 up 50 days, 15:15, 15 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.03

[user@login ~]$ vim file
[user@login ~]$ cd dir/foo
[user@login foo]$ mkdir bar
[user@login bar]$ cd bar
[user@login bar]$ vim file2
[user@login bar]$ ls
file2

[user@login bar]$
```

#### Motivation:

A new line improves readability, but it is only necessary when there is something to read.

Comment: This should be a shell feature, implementing it with external tools doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: It's an interesting question.  But I can't think of any reasonable mechanism by which the shell could even know whether the previous command produced any output.

Comment: I agree with @oguz. Do you think that using `PROMPT_COMMAND` and functions constitutes using "external tools"?

Comment: No, they are internal features but I don't think you can do this using them

Comment: Maybe your `PROMPT_COMMAND` could store and compare the vertical cursor position to guess whether there was an output. However, this method would also print newlines after silent multiline commands. Also, I have no idea how scrolling would affect this method.

Comment: pipe all outputs through awk like this somehow? `| awk '{ print $0"\n" }'` I don't know if it's possible to generically modify stdout with something like that

Comment: @Shardj: Even if you could, it would break basically all applications that interact with the user, if they are expecting for stdout to be a tty and it is a pipe instead.

Comment: Your motivation is improving readability. An alternative is a colored prompt. I use `PS1="\[\033[1;34m\]\u@docker:\[\033[0m\]\w\n$\[\033[0m\] "` on a dark blue blackground (and `colorscheme pablo` in `.vimrc`).

Comment: Adding color to the prompt does help with readability.